# Django Migrate ORA-00955 error

Tags: python, django, oracle

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en django 1.8.7 utilizando Linux Ubuntu 16 y conectado a una base de datos de Oracle 11g, al momento de querer migrar el proyecto utilizando el `python manage.py migrate` me lanza el siguiente error, alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

```
return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00955:
    name is already used by an existing object
```

Comment: Agrega mas información a tu pregunta, como codigo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como se genera la base de datos?

Comment: podrias usar algo asi: python manage.py migrate --fake-initial